# Is smartphone(likely Android) can be used for image processing unit?

Tags: android, image-processing, smartphone

I'm new in image processing.

I have a photocamera(not built-in in smartphone) that would use smartphone(likely Android) as processing unit. The cam will be placed on car's back or maybe car's roof(**let mark this car as X**) and the smartphone should alert if any other car aproaches to this car X or if other car drive strangely(goes right and left)...

My question is: can I use smartphone as processing unit for this kind of purpose or I'll need to have some server that would process the images and that server will sent the result to smartphone?

1 - If you think that smartphone(likely Android) could **NOT** manage this kind of image-processing tell me why please?

2 - If you think that smartphone(likely Android) **DO** could manage with this what tools I can use for this purpose?

Comment: why somebody voted to close this post? why I cannot use this site to debate or consult?

Comment: Not only can it be done, it has been done: Not using a separate camera, but using the built-in one.  The device definitely has the power to do the job.  Using an external camera poses a significant technical challenge of getting the photo into the Android.

Comment: @Sparky, could you mention the name of that application?

Comment: I don't want to give any appearance of partiality, so please don't take this as an endorsement either for or against.  The app is called iOnRoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly can be done. I've used a Eee PC (1.4 GHz Atom processor) for image processing (3D reconstruction) and it worked very well. The system as a whole wasn't powerful enough, but the issue here was other stuff not directly related to the image processing portion (path finding, etc.). Depending on what you're going to do, you shouldn't have any issues processing images at 15, 30 or even 60 Hz.

As a note: Ever checked Android's camera app (the default one)? Newer versions offer a "background" mode for video recordings, replacing the actual backdrop with other videos. This is essentially image processing.

As for tools: I'm not sure if there's a OpenCV port yet, but this really depends on what (and how) you want to do it. Simple tracking, depth detection, etc. can definitely be done without such libraries and without having to rewrite too much.

Comment: I'm not only tracking but I need to identify car from the video... Does this consider simple tracking, depth detection...?

Comment: I did full depth detection (i.e. compare a pair of stereo images to calculate the depth for each pixel) as well as tracking these "depth points" over several frames using an a/b filter. Basically you should be able to do anything you want, even if you're running low on power you'd just have to lower your framerate. It's trial & error due to algorithm complexity, processor power, etc.